# WooCommerce SagePay Server Integration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, opayo

These are my settings when I go to payment page I not able to choose the card.

Click the URL below to view the screenshots.

Admin Setting: http://betaurl.info/admin-setting.jpg

Live Website: http://betaurl.info/live-website.jpg

Comment: Live Website: http://betaurl.info/flyefg-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Trying to checkout from your site returns the error 'Transaction Failed. INVALID - 4020 : Information received from an Invalid IP address.'

You need to add your Server IP to 'Valid IPs' in your My Sage Pay settings.

Comment: This will be the external IP of your server. Could try logging on to it, and visiting whatismyip.com